# Bootstrap 5 - colored border on icons

Tags: css, icons, border, overlay, bootstrap-5

Is it possible to add a white border around the new BS5 icons? Working on a movie-page and have an icon overlay of a dice. On dark backgrounds the dice isn't even visible.

What I've tried so far:

- White background (bg-white): That leaves a filled white square with icon in the middle, not pretty.
- White border (border border-white): leaves a white bordered square around the icon. Also not pretty.

[image]

So what I am hoping to achieve is a white border that follows the outer edge of the icon (and also fill the dots with white if that's possible).

What I have so far:

```
<style>
.dice {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0 3px;
}
</style>

<div class="row row-cols-4 row-cols-md-6 g-3 mt-2">
    <?php foreach ($media as $row) { ?>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card h-100">
          <a href="movie_details.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $row['img']; ?>" class="card-img-top"></a>
          <div class="dice h3">
            <?php if($row['score'] == 1)
                { echo "<i class=\"bi bi-dice-1-fill\"></i>"; }
                else if($row['score'] == 2)
                { echo "<i class=\"bi bi-dice-2-fill\"></i>"; }
                else if($row['score'] == 3)
                { echo "<i class=\"bi bi-dice-3-fill\"></i>"; }
                else if($row['score'] == 4)
                { echo "<i class=\"bi bi-dice-4-fill\"></i>"; }
                else if($row['score'] == 5)
                { echo "<i class=\"bi bi-dice-5-fill\"></i>"; }
                else if($row['score'] == 6)
                { echo "<i class=\"bi bi-dice-6-fill\"></i>"; }
              ?>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about putting the icons inside of a container that you could then apply background color and border-radius attributes to and style them appropriately to match the icon:

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}

.diceContainer {
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0.2em;
  margin: 0;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  border-radius: 2em;
}

.bi-dice-5-fill {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: auto;
  color: black;
  font-size: 10em;
  line-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>BootStrap Icons</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.7.2/font/bootstrap-icons.css'>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="diceContainer">
      <i class='bi bi-dice-5-fill'></i>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap icons into div and set padding, background to it.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.item {
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
}
.item img {
  width: 100%;
}
.item .icon-wrap {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  z-index: 2;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 1px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap Font Icon CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" alt="">
  <div class="icon-wrap">
    <i class="bi bi-dice-5-fill"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```